# Consfiguration Section Designer - how to fix broken XSD?

Tags: configuration, designer, configurationsection

Hi I have used Consfiguration Section Designer to design custom config section some time ago.
Recently I found that XSD file generated by the designer is broken, instead of XSD schema it contains just error message (XSD is gone):

```
An exception occured while running the CsdFileGenerator on this file. See the Error List for details. E=System.InvalidOperationException: TextTemplating service unavailable
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.BaseTemplatedCodeGenerator.GenerateCode(String inputFileName, String inputFileContent)
   at ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator.GenerateAllContent(String fileExtension)
   at ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator.GenerateContent(String element)
   at ConfigurationSectionDesigner.VsMultipleFileGenerator`1.Generate(String wszInputFilePath, String bstrInputFileContents, String wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, UInt32& pcbOutput, IVsGeneratorProgress pGenerateProgress)
```

Is there any way to regenerate the XSD ?

Thanks.